# Curl request in python

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, libcurl, google-trends

I'm a newbie to python program. I want to get trending topics in google trends. How do i make this curl request from python

```
curl --data "ajax=1&htd=20131111&pn=p1&htv=l" http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/hotItems
```

I tried following code

```
param = {"data" :"ajax=1&htd=20131111&pn=p1&htv=l"} 
value = urllib.urlencode(param)

req = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems", value)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read()
print result
```

But it is not returning expected values, which is the current Google trends.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the `data` element in your `curl` command line; that is the *already encoded* POST body, while you are wrapping it in another `data` key and encoding again.

Either use *just* the value (and not encode it again), or put the individual elements in a dictionary and urlencode that:

```
value = "ajax=1&htd=20131111&pn=p1&htv=l"
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems", value)
```

or

```
param = {'ajax': '1', 'htd': '20131111', 'pn': 'p1', 'htv': 'l'}
value = urllib.urlencode(param)
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems", value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib, urllib2
>>> value = "ajax=1&htd=20131111&pn=p1&htv=l"
>>> req = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems", value)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> json.load(response).keys()
[u'trendsByDateList', u'lastPage', u'summaryMessage', u'oldestVisibleDate', u'dataUpdateTime']
>>> param = {'ajax': '1', 'htd': '20131111', 'pn': 'p1', 'htv': 'l'}
>>> value = urllib.urlencode(param)
>>> value
'htv=l&ajax=1&htd=20131111&pn=p1'
>>> req = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems", value)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> json.load(response).keys()
[u'trendsByDateList', u'lastPage', u'summaryMessage', u'oldestVisibleDate', u'dataUpdateTime']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest using the `requests` library in Python. Here's an example using Python 2.7:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'ajax': 1, 'htd': '20131111', 'pn':'p1', 'htv':'l'}
req = requests.post('http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/hotItems', data=payload)

print req.status_code # Prints out status code
print json.loads(req.text) # Prints out json data
```